# Changing the path in aws

Tags: 14.04, scripts, backup, mysql, aws

I have script which backs up mysql database into aws. I need to **add a code to the script which deletes the databases after backup is successful onto aws**. Can someone guide me with the code. Here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Basic variables
mysqlpass="mysql"
bucket="s3://akshaysolutionbackup/orbit/"

# Timestamp (sortable AND readable)
stamp=`date +"%d-%m-%Y"`

# List all the databases
databases=`mysql -u root -pmysql -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | tr -d "| " | grep -v "\(Database\|information_schema\|performance_schema\)"`

# Feedback
echo -e "Dumping to \e[1;32m$bucket/$stamp/\e[00m"

# Loop the databases
for db in $databases; do

# Define our filenames
filename="$stamp - $db.sql.gz"
tmpfile="/tmp/$filename"
object="$bucket/$stamp/$filename"

# Feedback
echo -e "\e[1;34m$db\e[00m"

# Dump and zip
echo -e "  creating \e[0;35m$tmpfile\e[00m"
mysqldump -u root -pmysql --force --opt --databases "$db" | gzip -c > $tmpfile"

# Upload
echo -e "  uploading..."
s3cmd put "$tmpfile" "$object"

# Delete
rm -f "$tmpfile"
done;

# Jobs a goodun
echo -e "\e[1;32mJobs a goodun\e[00m"
```

Comment: Kindly excuse for typing the entire script as i could't get the link working for the script

Comment: **The link to the script is here**  https://gist.github.com/oodavid/2206527#file-s3mysqlbackup-sh

Comment: You could just do something like `echo "drop database $db" | mysql -u root -pmysql`. Is that what you want?

Comment: I want that to be done by the script itself, once all the backup is successful. Where to add the code? I will be adding the script into crontab.

Comment: You can add the command as I gave it to the script, before the `done`; or you could do another loop, like: `for db in databases; do echo "drop database $db" | mysql -u root -pmysql done` at the end of the script.

Comment: The above code worked!!

Comment: Good! Allow me to post it as an answer, then.

Comment: Sorry, i am new to stack overflow. May i know what i need to do now?

Comment: I am working on an answer right now. After I post it, if it is to your satisfaction, please click the check mark next to it to mark the question as "answered".

Comment: Okay then sure i will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to delete a database from within a script is:

`echo "drop database dbname" | mysql -u username -ppassword`

This will start up the `mysql` command line client and execute the SQL statement that was piped into it by the `echo` command. In your script, you can either delete the database as soon as it has been backed up:

`echo "drop database $db" | mysql -u username -ppassword`

(within the `do`/`done` loop), or wait until the end of the script, when the whole backup is complete, and then do another loop through the databases and drop all of them:

```
for db in databases; do
  echo "drop database $db" | mysql -u username -ppassword
done;
```